# How to enable only specific dates in calendar view from database

Tags: android, json, calendarview

I have a Calendar view in my activity, I want to enable only the dates which are coming from the database, I have disabled the previous dates. I just have to enable the dates which are coming from the server. The postman JSON body of dates as follows:

```
  "data": [
        {
            "date": "2020-12-30",
            "time1": "08:42 PM",
            "time2": "07:42 PM",
            "time3": "09:42 PM",
            "time4": "10:42 PM"
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-31",
            "time1": "07:43 PM",
            "time2": "09:43 PM",
            "time3": "07:43 PM",
            "time4": "05:43 PM"
        },
        ...
    ]
```

The date is in the key "**date**", im fetching the dates and other fields  in my activity as follows:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            //Detail myDetail = new Detail(jsonObject.getString("name"), jsonObject.getString("imageurl"));
                            String strDate  = jsonObject.getString("date");
                            strT1    = jsonObject.getString("time1");
                            strT2    = jsonObject.getString("time2");
                            strT3    = jsonObject.getString("time3");
                            strT4    = jsonObject.getString("time4");
}
```

Now the dates I'm getting in this string **strDate** here what to do next, I have to enable these dates on the calendar view and rest all the dates should be disabled, can anyone help me please or is there any other custom calendar can I use to achieve this thanks!

Comment: You can use the Material Date Picker and supply a [CalendarConstraints](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/CalendarConstraints.java) instance with your configuration to disable the days you don't want. Check the [Material Design Date Picker](https://material.io/components/date-pickers/android#customization) Implementation.